# Are ElasticSearch snapshots independent of the ElasticSearch version

Tags: elasticsearch

If I make a snapshot using ElasticSearch version 1.5 can I deploy it to an ElasticSearch 2.0 cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-upgrade.html):

> Elasticsearch 2.x (Lucene 5) can read disk formats from Elasticsearch
>   0.90 and 1.x (Lucene 4), but not from Elasticsearch 0.20 and before (Lucene 3).

But definitely do a dry-run first though to make sure everything works as expected.